# how to get the relative position of shapes within a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, position, shapes

If you think of cells, we know logically that Row 2 is higher than row 100.

However If I had two shapes (lets say circles) how do I determine which one is higher than the other, or further left than the rest?

**UPDTAE**

- Where is the Object model for all Objects and methods / attributes for things like 1. charts >> The Top left

[image]

Comment: Look at the shape object's `.TopLeftCell.Address`

Comment: but are shapes always aligned to cells, or can they be free. 

I am skilled with VBA but I have never been able to find a full OBJECT MODEL for VBA listing all the objects (wksht, wb, shapes, charts, pivot, etc) only bits and pieces from other peoples tutorials.

Comment: Not aligned, but it does know what the top-left-most cell the shape occupies is.  You can use that as a reference.  If you'd rather not use cell references, shapes also have `.Top` and `.Left` properties.  0 indicates the shape is all the way at top, or all the way at left

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22731978/2521004) might help you.

Comment: [Excel Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068(v=office.14).aspx). You should be able to drill down in to any of the pieces, like [Chart object members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837379(v=office.14).aspx) (i.e., methods and properties), or the [Shape object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193908(v=office.14).aspx), etc.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some code to display the row for each Shape:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As Shape, mesage As String
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        mesage = mesage & vbCrLf & s.Name & "---" & s.TopLeftCell.Row
    Next s
    MsgBox mesage
End Sub
```