# how to get the cell location of an extracted image using zipfile python in Linux

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I am trying to extract images from an excel file to the disk using `zipfile` `python`

```
import zipfile
InputName = "TestExcel.xlsx"

Extracteds = zipfile.ZipFile(InputName).namelist()
ImageFiles = [E for E in Extracteds if E.count('.jpg') or E.count('.jpeg') ]

for i in ImageFiles:
    print "----> ",zipfile.ZipFile(InputName).extract(i)
```

How to get the cell location of those images?

Here I am getting the path of images printed out and all images extracted to the folder on disk

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52069292/9050514

Comment: I am trying to install win32 client in ubuntu machine, but it throws an error for _winreg which is only supported by windows as stated here https://docs.python.org/release/2.1.2/lib/module--winreg.html @deadshot